# Are self-referential set comprehensions allowed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I define the following set:
$$
    C = \{ \{n\} \cup D \mid n \in \mathbb{N},  D \in C \} \cup \{\emptyset\}.
$$

Then intuitively, $C$ is the set of all subsets of the natural numbers. However, is $C$, as it stands, well-defined? Its definition refers back to itself - is this "allowed"?

Comment: Why should you think that this would solely refer back to the set of all subsets of natural numbers?  Supposing that $C=\{D\subseteq \Bbb R~:~\exists n\in D\cap \Bbb N\}\cup \emptyset$, the set of all subsets of real numbers containing at least one natural number or are empty instead, is there any contradiction with saying $C=\{\{n\}\cup D~|~n\in\Bbb N,~D\in C\}\cup \emptyset$?  What you write isn't strong enough to uniquely identify this set as a definition since multiple different sets satisfy this equation.

Comment: As to the question of whether it is "allowed," I cannot think of a useful example which uniquely identifies the set as part of the definition of the set itself, but see no reason why it should be outlawed entirely... just avoided when possible to prevent ambiguity.  It is useful however for pointing out certain properties, such as in your case the set $C$ is "*closed under union with subsets of natural numbers*", i.e. For all $D\in C$ you have $D\cup E\in C$ where $E\subseteq \Bbb N$.

Comment: I think you meant $\ldots \cup \{ \varnothing \}$?

Answer (score 4):

The right way to think about this is you've specified an *equation* in the variable $C$. This equation might have none, one, or more solutions.

If it turns out to have exactly one solution, then you could define a set to be that solution.

If it has more than one solution, you can't define a set to be *the* solution. However, you could still introduce a new variable to refer to the choice of *some* solution.

If it has no solutions, then of course you can't (in standard logic) introduce any set at all satisfying the equation.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not allowed. In general.

Sure, there might be sets which do satisfy this condition, and *no*, the set of all subsets of $\Bbb N$ will definitely not satisfy this since $\varnothing$ does not satisfy the condition that $\varnothing=\{n\}\cup D$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ and $D\in C$, unless $C$ itself is empty (in which case it is certainly not $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)$).

For example, $C=\{\Bbb N\}$ satisfies this condition, as would $\varnothing$, vacuously. Even $\{\Bbb N\setminus\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ satisfies this; and so will $\{\Bbb N\setminus A\mid A\subseteq\Bbb N, A\text{ is finite}\}$.

---

But as you can see, this condition does not specify a unique set. And for a good reason. Defining a set in terms of itself is rarely a logically valid definition (sure, you do have $X=\{x\mid x\in X\}$, and that's fine). So in general we try to avoid defining a set using itself.

The key issue here is that a definition should be satisfied by a *unique* set. And if you give a condition which is not satisfied by a unique set, then it is not a good definition for a set. If you have a definition, and you can prove that only one set can satisfy this definition—even if you used that same set as part of your definition—that's fine. But this is rarely the case with "self-referential definitions", and one has to be extra careful not to run into problems. So it's generally a good rule of thumb, that unless you know what you're doing, don't use a set in its own definition.